# Date problem in magento sales grid

Tags: magento-1.9, php-5.4, order-grid, delivery-date

I have added the delivery date column to Order Gird, showing good. But it's showing less than one day.

```
Example: Actual date is 24th Dec 2014. But it's showing 23rd Dec 2014.
```

**From database also saved as 24th Dec 2014.**

how can I solve this?

**my code is:**

```
<?php
class Easylife_CustomGrid_Block_Adminhtml_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('sales_order_grid');
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
        $this->setDefaultSort('created_at');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve collection class
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getCollectionClass()
    {
        return 'sales/order_grid_collection';
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());


        $collection->getSelect()->join(
            array("sales" => 'sales_flat_order'),
            "main_table.entity_id = sales.entity_id"
        );


        //$collection->printLogQuery(true);

        //Mage::log($collection);

        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {


        $this->addColumn('real_order_id', array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order #'),
            'width' => '80px',
            'type'  => 'text',
            'index' => 'increment_id',
        ));

        if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
            $this->addColumn('store_id', array(
                'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased from (store)'),
                'index'     => 'store_id',
                'type'      => 'store',
                'store_view'=> true,
                'display_deleted' => true,
                'filter_index' => 'main_table.store_id'
            ));
        }

        $this->addColumn('created_at', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased On'),
            'index' => 'created_at',
            'type' => 'datetime',
            'width' => '100px',
            'filter_index' => 'main_table.created_at'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('billing_name', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Bill to Name'),
            'index' => 'billing_name',
        ));


        $this->addColumn('shipping_arrival_date', array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Delivery Date'),
            'width' => '80px',
            'type'  => 'datetime',
            'index' => 'shipping_arrival_date',
            'filter_index' => 'main_table.shipping_arrival_date'
        ));



        $this->addColumn('base_grand_total', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Base)'),
            'index' => 'base_grand_total',
            'type'  => 'currency',
            'currency' => 'base_currency_code',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('grand_total', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Purchased)'),
            'index' => 'grand_total',
            'type'  => 'currency',
            'currency' => 'order_currency_code',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('status', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Status'),
            'index' => 'status',
            'type'  => 'options',
            'width' => '70px',
            'options' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getStatuses(),
        ));


        return $this;
    }

    protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        $this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('order_ids');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setUseSelectAll(false);

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/cancel')) {
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('cancel_order', array(
                'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Cancel'),
                'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massCancel'),
            ));
        }

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/hold')) {
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('hold_order', array(
                'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Hold'),
                'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massHold'),
            ));
        }

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/unhold')) {
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('unhold_order', array(
                'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Unhold'),
                'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massUnhold'),
            ));
        }

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfinvoices_order', array(
            'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Invoices'),
            'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfinvoices'),
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfshipments_order', array(
            'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Packingslips'),
            'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfshipments'),
        ));


        return $this;
    }

    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
            return $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $row->getId()));
        }
        return false;
    }
    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
    }

}
```

**Where I went wrong?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I solved..

find below solutions..

```
<?php
class Easylife_CustomGrid_Block_Adminhtml_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('sales_order_grid');
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
        $this->setDefaultSort('created_at');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }

    protected function _getCollectionClass()
    {
        return 'sales/order_grid_collection';
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
        $collection->getSelect()->join(
            array("sales" => 'sales_flat_order'),
            "main_table.entity_id = sales.entity_id"
        );



        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {

        $this->addColumn('shipping_arrival_date', array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Delivery Date'),
            'width' => '80px',
            'type'  => 'datetime',
            /*'format'    => 'd/M/YY a',*/
            'index' => 'shipping_arrival_date',
            'renderer' => new Easylife_CustomGrid_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Data(),
            'filter_index' => 'main_table.shipping_arrival_date'
        ));

        return $this;
    }

}
```

and `Data.php` file

```
<?php

class Easylife_CustomGrid_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Data extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Action
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        return $this->_getValue($row);
    }

    public function _getValue(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $val = $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());  // row value
        $manoj_kumar = strtotime($val);
        $newformat = date('d/M/Y',$manoj_kumar);
        //$date_val = date_format($val, 'd/M/Y H:i:s');
        //Mage::log($newformat);
        return $newformat;

    }
}
```